# make elasticsearch fill a field with dummy variables

Tags: elasticsearch, crossfilter

I want to use data from elasticsearch in crossfilter. For me to be able to use crossfilter I need to have all variables present for every record. For example, if we have a tweet; all tweets should have `[date, hashtags,text]` otherwise if one of the tweets does not have 'hashtags', the tweet properties would be `['date','text']`.

How can I structure an `elasticsearch` query that would return [date, hashtags,text] even for a tweet with only `['date','text']` and set `hashtags` to some dummy variable?